# getting error 'Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found' while using RestTemplate in Spring MVC,but works fine in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, resttemplate

My RestTemplate code

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Courses courses = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8090/apple/courses", Courses.class);
```

If I run the same code from a SpringBoot application it works fine, but if I run in from a Spring MVC application I am getting the below error,

Both the application has the same Courses class.

```
Message Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.danny.model.Course] and content type [application/json]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.danny.model.Course] and content type [application/json]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1019)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
Root Cause

org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.danny.model.Course] and content type [application/json]
    org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:865)
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:764)
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:378)
    com.danny.controllers.MainController.welcome(MainController.java:81)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Comment: brief your courses api code

Comment: I need to double check, but I believe Spring Boot auto-configures some default HttpMessageConverters, including one for `application/json`, while I suppose Spring MVC doesn't

Comment: could you add your destination API too ?